# Transfer Learning Accuracy Drop after Rerun

Tags: tf.keras, transfer-learning

I had use below code to perform Transfer Learning with Inception by testing different optimizer and other setting.
However, I face the training accuracy drop from 70% to 20% after I try to put the model with selected optimizer with dense value in loop.

My Code for different optimizer

```
# Create the InceptionV3 base model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(input_shape[0], input_shape[1], 3))
base_model.trainable = False

# Add custom classification layers on top of the base model
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

learningrate = 0.0001
epochs_values = 1
optimzers = [tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learningrate),
            tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=learningrate),
            tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learningrate),
            tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=learningrate),
            tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=learningrate),
            tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(learning_rate=learningrate),
            tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=learningrate)]

optmizer_list =["Adam","RMSprop","SGD","Adadelta","Adagrad","Adamax","Nadam"]
train_accuracy_list =[]
train_loss_list =[]
val_accuracy_list = []
val_loss_list = []
test_accuracy_list =[]
test_loss_list = []

for i, j in zip(optimzers, optmizer_list):
    print("Current Optimizer is " + j)
    model_diff_optimizer = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=outputs)
    model_diff_optimizer.compile( optimizer = i, 
                                 loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                                 metrics=['accuracy'])
    train_history = model_diff_optimizer.fit(train_generator,
                             epochs =epochs_values, 
                             validation_data=valid_generator)
    test_loss, test_acc = model_diff_optimizer.evaluate(test_generator)
    
    print('Test accuracy for ', j,":" , test_acc)

    train_accuracy_list.append(train_history.history['accuracy'])
    train_loss_list.append(train_history.history['loss'])
    val_accuracy_list.append(train_history.history['val_accuracy'])
    val_loss_list.append(train_history.history['val_loss'])
    test_accuracy_list.append(test_acc)
    test_loss_list.append(test_loss)
```

my code for different dense but with selected optimizer

```
dense = ["256", "512", "1024", "2048"]
learningrate = 0.0001
epochs_values = 1

train_accuracy_list =[]
train_loss_list =[]
val_accuracy_list = []
val_loss_list = []
test_accuracy_list =[]
test_loss_list = []

for i in dense:
    print("Current dense is " + str(i))
    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(i, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    
    model_diff_dense = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=outputs)

    model_diff_dense.compile( optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=learningrate), 
                                 loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                                 metrics=['accuracy'])
    train_history = model_diff_dense.fit(train_generator,
                             epochs =epochs_values, 
                             validation_data=valid_generator)
    test_loss, test_acc = model_diff_dense.evaluate(test_generator)
    
    print('Test accuracy for ', i,":" , test_acc)

    train_accuracy_list.append(train_history.history['accuracy'])
    train_loss_list.append(train_history.history['loss'])
    val_accuracy_list.append(train_history.history['val_accuracy'])
    val_loss_list.append(train_history.history['val_loss'])
    test_accuracy_list.append(test_acc)
    test_loss_list.append(test_loss)
```

I tried to rerun the test for different denese value

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?
Why are you using that many optimizers?
Also: What data do you want to train?
Where do you retrain your model? Do you just want to use the architecture of Inception?

Comment: I just want to test whether different optimizer, different dense and different learning rate will have different outcome of training accuracy

Comment: That's what I undestood, but do you have data to train the Neural Network? Because just using optimizers without actually training it, won't do anything significant... If you just train one epoch and used a pretrained model, the accuracy drop is acutally what I expect... Because the neural network has never seen your data.

Comment: A question: Do you think an optimizer just optimizes a pretrained neural network? Because that is certainly not the case.

Comment: @SickerDude43, yes, I have input 6250 images to train the data
Actually this is a part of my assignment that request us to modify the transfer learning method to see the difference of the result by changing the own output layer, change trainable layer, change optimizer, epochs and learning rate